# Component livepreview limited to 160 x 160px

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components

Hail Stack!

I'm developing a component in Flash (CS5).
This one isn't useful, it's just to learn how to do it.

One of my troubles so far isn't a big one, but the livepreview has being limited to 160px wide and high...
Can anyone tell me why, or how to get rid of this limitation?

**Edit**: I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html) and made the menu strip. In the livepreview, as it gets wider, it gets cropped.
Then, I made another one, for the sake of certainty, and found out that the problem persists.

I've made a box with adjustable width and height.
After publishing, everything is OK, but in livepreview don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you been following Jeff Kamerer's [Creating ActionScript 3.0 components in Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html)?  he describes, in length, how to create a component for flash - including creating live previews:

[Part 3: From prototype to component:  Implementing Live Preview](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components_pt3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_6)

Comment: Ya, I'm following exactly this tutorial, which is a great one, very well described. But it doesn't addresses to my problem. ps: +1 for the tutorial tip

Answer (score 0):

It might be cropping your preview to the size of the actual graphics of your component. You could try putting a big box in your component, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: My component is a menu strip (following [Creating ActionScript 3.0 components in Flash, by Jeff Kamerer](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html)) and while it gets wider, it gets cropped.